# How to add current user generic detail view?

Tags: django

I am learning Django by following an application tutorial written by others called "portfolio". The code is available at http://www.lightbird.net/dbe/. I tried to modify the code so when a user submits a picture, the current user's name can be saved as "creator" defined in model.py as part of the image model. I have a hard time to make this work since I either got the error of unexpected argument of "dpk" or an error related to the number of arguments in "POST" function. Can someone help?  Here are the information I have. I highlighted the part of the codes added, which are not part of the original.

models.py:

```
class Image(BaseModel):
    title       = CharField(max_length=60, blank=True, null=True)
    description = TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    image       = ImageField(upload_to="images/")
    thumbnail1  = ImageField(upload_to="images/", blank=True, null=True)
    thumbnail2  = ImageField(upload_to="images/", blank=True, null=True)

    width       = IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    height      = IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    hidden      = BooleanField(default=True)
    group       = ForeignKey(Group, related_name="images", blank=True)
    created     = DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    creator     = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True)
    ##########################################################
    def save(self,**kwargs):
      if kwargs.has_key('request') and self.creator is None:
            self.creator= kwargs['request'].creator
            super(Image, self).save(**kwargs)
```

forms.py:

```
class AddImageForm(f.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model   = Image
        exclude = "width height hidden group thumbnail1 thumbnail2    
    creator".split()
        attrs   = dict(cols=70, rows=2)
        widgets = dict( description=f.Textarea(attrs=attrs) )
    #####################################################################
    def save(self, commit=True , *args, **kwargs):
            m = super(AddImageForm, self).save(commit=False, *args, **kwargs)
            if m.creator is None and kwargs.has_key('request'):
              m.creator= kwargs['request'].creator
              m.save()
```

views.py:

```
class AddImages(DetailView, FormSetView):
    """Add images to a group view."""
    detail_model       = Group
    formset_model      = Image
    formset_form_class = AddImageForm
    template_name      = "add_images.html"
    extra              = 1
    ############################################################
    def post(self, request):
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save(request=request)
    ############################################################
    def process_form(self, form):
        form.instance.update( group=self.get_detail_object() )

    def get_success_url(self):
        return self.detail_absolute_url()
```

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns("portfolio.views",
    (r"^group/(?P<dpk>\d+)/(?P<show>\S+)/" , GroupView.as_view(), {}, 
     "group"),
    (r"^group/(?P<dpk>\d+)/"               , GroupView.as_view(), {}, 
     "group"),
    (r"^add-images/(?P<dpk>\d+)/"          , AddImages.as_view(), {}, 
    "add_images"),
    (r"^slideshow/(?P<dpk>\d+)/"           , SlideshowView.as_view(), {}, 
    "slideshow"),
    (r"^image/(?P<mfpk>\d+)/"              , ImageView.as_view(), {}, 
    "image"),
    (r"^image/"                            , ImageView.as_view(), {}, 
    "image"),
    (r""                                   , Main.as_view(), {},   
    "portfolio"),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You've overridden the `post` method in your view to only take the request, but your URLs are passing it the `dpk` parameter.

You should not be overriding `post` anyway. The logic you have there should happen in `form_valid`.

(Also, you should reflect on whether you really need the same logic in three places. I would put *all* this code in `form_valid`, and not override save on the form or the model at all.)

Comment: Thanks! Dan. As you suggested I created a formset_valid function in views.py and passed request.user to creator in each individual form in the formset. It works perfectly. I am really motivated to explore more in django.